How to share information between browser tabs that are opened from specific tab
If I open an app (SPA) in multiple tabs (manually opened tabs), I want to make some of the information persistent as a session for each tab. Session storage does this job.
But when I right click on an anchor and then select "open in new tab" in specific tab, I want to pass that session storage into the new opened tab.
The local storage does not work for this, because I want each tab to hold independent data, but those tabs that are opened from another tab to access the opener data.
There should be a place to keep a data in each tab, where:

Tabs that are opened from another tab, to have access to that opener place
Tabs that are manually opened to not be able to read data from that place

When I middle-click with the mouse on the refresh button of the browser, It opens a new tab and passes the session storage from the current tab into the new opened tab. I want something like this to happen when I right click and select "open in new tab" on an anchor.
How I can achieve this behaviour?
Without adding information to the link URL/query params

Maybe I just don't get it, but aren't your requirements contradicting each other? Regarding " ... I want each tab to hold independent data, but those tabs that are opened from another tab to access the opener data ... " - either you want them to hold independent data or shared data. If a tab has access to data that has been set in another tab, the data is not independent regardless how the tab has been opened.

on load - copy localStorage to sessionStorage. on focus - copy sessionStorage to localStorage

localStorage is the simplest answer. Web Workers are a bit more complex, but could also solve the issue.

I want the tabs to be independent.  But also those that are opened as new tab from a tab, to be able to access the session storage from the opener tab, like cloning it from tab to tap, by value, not by reference

You can use window.name and sessionStorage together.
Set data in window.name for the new tab:
function openTabWithData(url) {
    const data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
    
    const newTab = window.open(url, '_blank');
    newTab.onload = function() {
        newTab.name = data
    }
}

Retrieve the data in the new tab and store it in sessionStorage:
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  if (window.name) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('key', window.name);
    window.name = '';
  }
});

Example usage:
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openTabWithData('myNewTab.html')">Open in New Tab</a>


Each tab has its own session data

Tabs opened from another tab can access the shared data

Tabs manually opened don't have access to the data.



I don't want to break the existing behaviour of the links. It is not just a click, it is right click and open in new tab or ctrl + left click

@OktayYuzcan It could have been possible with window.opener, but I couldn't find a reliable way to do this. The only case where it worked was by setting target="_blank" and rel="opener", and even then, it only worked by clicking the link directly. Otherwise, window.opener is null.
